# Battery shows 13v after adding acid but won't start car

Tags: battery

My car battery won't start the car so I added acid and water and test the density with a hydrometer, now it is 1250. The battery light is turned green after adding acid, but voltage reach 13 (I don't charge it after adding). No matter have I drain it, it reach to 13v again. I can't start the car by the way.

Why it is 13v? How to recover it to start the car?

Comment: It's not clear to me, but have you charged the battery? Traditional lead-acid batteries still need to be charged after being filled (or topped off).

Comment: It could be showing 13V on a meter but still not have enough amperage to start the car. Remember Volts and current(amps) are not the same thing and you need to consider them both.

Comment: @narkeleptk, the battery is not charged after filling because it show 13v. How much I charge it to be enough?

Comment: @SAMPro you need to get a battery charger like this: https://www.sears.com/schumacher-sc1359-fully-automatic-battery-charger-15-amps/p-SPM14570399810  They come in automatic and manual varieties. Manual tends to be cheaper but you have to check on it repeatedly to make sure you don't overcharge the battery.

Comment: @zaen, how to check for overcharge in manual mode?

Comment: @SAMPro Manual gauges, at least the ones I've used and seen, have a "% charged" scale in addition to the voltage scale. Just make sure you don't go past 100%. Above all else, read the manual for your particular charger so you know how to use it.